# No "Surface" on Materials Properties

Tags: materials, interface

Just learning Blender this week and Immediately I'm stuck at some point. I cannot add COLOR because under MATERIAL, there is no choice for SURFACE > COLOR.

[image]

I'm so stuck. Help :)

Comment: You are using Blender Render. Change Blender Render in the top bar to  Cycles.

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to add a simple color in *Blender Render* open the *Diffuse* tab
- If you want the *Surface* tab then switch to *Cycle Render* (on the topbar, the dropdown juste after "Scene")

Answer (score 0):

Surface color feature is available only in Cycles Render, to enable **Surface** tab please follow the steps as shown in the image below:
[image]

1. Change the Cycles Render
2. Go to the Surface tab -> Use nodes -> Set the color of your choice
3. Change the Viewport shading to Material

If you want to stick with the blender render (which is not recommended) please go to diffuse tab and take a look of the image below to apply color:
[image]

Comment: Hey thanks guys, I was able to figure it out myself too. Appreciate the replies :)